# Matrix conversion OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: matrix, opengl-es, projection

I would like to know how I can use this matrix in my custom GL renderer to implement pinch zoom. I keep getting an error that is telling me I cannot set an opengl.Matrix which is type float[16] with the Matrix object I am changing in my activity below. What is the correct way to pass my graphics.matrix through such that it will update my view correctly? As a workaround I am passing the newDist value to my renderer, but then every time I touch the screen with 2 fingers, it resets the eyeZ value, so I think I really need to get this matrix to work so it holds my zoom values.

```
@Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
        start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
        Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        oldDist = spacing(event);
        Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
        if (oldDist > 10f) {
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            midPoint(mid, event);
            mode = ZOOM;
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        mode = NONE;
        Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        if (mode == ZOOM) {
            final float newDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
            if (newDist > 10f) {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                mGLSurfaceView.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mGLSurfaceView.setMyMatrix(newDist);
                        Log.d(TAG, "runnable exists");
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        break;
}

return true; // indicate event was handled
```

}